# How do you set an exclusive value for media queries?

Tags: css

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    /* stuff to do when the screen is >= 768px */
}
```

But what I need is to set a value when the screen is at maximum, 767.9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999px.

Because Bootstrap does their breakpoints mobile first I am having to redefine some css.

```
 .red-when-small-green-when-not-small {
    color:red;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .red-when-small-green-when-not-small {
        color: green;
    }
}
```

Meanwhile, that it should be green is already defined.

**master.css**:

```
.red-when-small-green-when-not-small {
    color: green;
}
```

You see what I'm saying? I end up having to say that I want it green twice in order to avoid that 1px zone where the min-max media queries don't match up.

Comment: There shouldn't be any in-between 767 and 768px. I've personally never encountered that situation. Mobile first css is the correct way to do responsive layouts. Your bigger widths should override the smaller ones. Please share a codepen demonstrating your problem.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. As long as you put your css after the Bootstrap stuff, you should be fine, even if you use the same breakpoints, i.e. `min-width: 768px`. By the way, with fractional numbers in general, I wouldn't count on precision higher than single precision float. In this case, 767.9998 would be the closest you could get.

Comment: @Geuis Oh, make no mistake, fractional pixels are real! And problematic! There are several question on this site where problems exist because windows were, say, 699.5 logical pixels wide on a Retina screen.

Answer (score 0):

did you try max-width?

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767.99px) {
    .red-when-small-green-when-not-small {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't on this particular example but I have wrestled with that approach in the past. I never got it to fully work and eventually gave in to the mobile-first approach. But just now I'm realizing how much work it takes to do mobile first when you don't start coding that way until half-way through. ...it's like switching from ac to dc.

Comment: if you don't start coding that way until halfway through, then by definition, it's not "mobile first".  =)

Comment: it's mobile second first, which is one more than mobile first.